# How to Insert hyperlink in a spreadsheet file using Google Spreadsheet API

Tags: google-sheets, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api

I see its possible to insert a hyperlink in a spreadsheet using spreadsheet API.
But I am facing issues in it. My payload to the API is given below.
Seems like some property is missing.

```
{
          "sheets": [
            {
              "data": [
                {
                  "rowData": [
                    {
                      "values": [
                        {
                          "hyperlink": "wwww.google.com",
                          "userEnteredValue": {
                            "stringValue": "google"
                          }
                        },
                        {
                          "hyperlink": "wwww.google.com",
                          "userEnteredValue": {
                          "formulaValue":"=HYPERLINK"
                          }
                        },
                        {
                          "hyperlink": "wwww.google.com",
                          "userEnteredValue": {
                            "stringValue": "google"
                          }
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ],
              "properties": {
                "title": "my testing",
                "sheetId": 0
              }
            }
          ],
          "properties": {
            "title": "My Test"
          }
        }
```

Is there something I am missing?I have tried multiple combinations of properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You want to create new Spreadsheet including the cell values using the method of spreadsheets.create in Sheets API.

  - From your request body, I imaged like above.
- You want to put the cell values which have the hyperlink when new Spreadsheet is created.
- You want to know the request body for achieving above.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer?

#### Modification points:

When the official document is seen, `hyperlink` is the read-only like below.

> hyperlink: A hyperlink this cell points to, if any. This field is read-only. (To set it, use a =HYPERLINK formula in the userEnteredValue.formulaValue field.)

So in your case, it is required to use the following property.

```
"userEnteredValue": {"formulaValue": "=HYPERLINK(\"wwww.google.com\",\"google\")"},
```

#### Modified request body:

When your request body is modified, it becomes as follows.

```
{
  "sheets": [
    {
      "data": [
        {
          "rowData": [
            {
              "values": [
                {
                  "userEnteredValue": {
                    "formulaValue": "=HYPERLINK(\"wwww.google.com\",\"google\")"
                  }
                },
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "properties": {
        "title": "my testing",
        "sheetId": 0
      }
    }
  ],
  "properties": {
    "title": "My Test"
  }
}
```

- In this request body, the new Spreadsheet which has the hyperlink at the cell "A1" is created.

#### References:

- [Method: spreadsheets.create](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/create)
- [CellData](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/cells#CellData)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.

Comment: Perfect solution indeed.
"formulaValue": "=HYPERLINK(\"wwww.google.com\",\"google\")"

Comment: @user1994 Thank you for your response.